# Onde devo colocar as classes model (POCO) em uma solution C#?

Tags: c#, arquitetura-de-software, model, organização-de-projeto, poco

Atualmente minha solution esta organizada mais ou menos assim:

- View (Windows Forms)
- DAL (Acesso a dados, retornam entidades de negócio)
- BLL (regras de negócio em geral)
- Model (POCO's que representam alguma entidade de negócio)

Aqui esta um exemplo de como seria uma classe da camada DAL

```
public ClienteModel ObterPorId(int id)
{
    // Código que consulta o banco e retorna um ClienteModel     
}

public List<ClienteModel> ObterTodos()
{
    // Código que consulta o banco e retorna uma lista de ClienteModel     
}
```

Note que eu separei as `Models` em uma DLL específica, porém, quando preciso obter uma entidade do banco preciso fazer using da `DAL` e da `Model` e isso esta me parecendo redundante.
Já vi projetos onde as `Models` ficavam armazenadas dentro da própria dll `DAL`.

Isso me parece fazer sentido pois todos os tipos (DALs, Models, etc) estariam embarcados na mesma dll.

Isso é uma boa prática/aconselhável ou existe algum bom motivo para separar as Models em uma DLL específica?

Comment: Separe o `Models` da classe `Dal` esse é o correto, imagine você criar uma lista de Clientes onde cada item represente uma classe `Dal`, isso sim é problemático ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic No meu caso, eu tenho uma classe Cliente que esta na DLL Models e uma classe ClienteRepositorio que esta na DLL DAL, a classe repositório tem um método com essa assinatura. public List<Cliente> ObterTodos(); por isso entendo que eu não teria este problema que vc descreveu.

Comment: Tem problemas sim porque todos os itens da lista teria esse método no seu caso antigo ainda não mas, se mudar para `List<DalCliente>` vai ter problemas de desempenho, mas, você faz aquilo que acha melhor eu só estou indicando que não é necessário e o jeito que está fazendo não é redundante, redundante é aquilo que é feito mais que uma vez (existe redundância de backup isso é bom, mas, de código não) e no caso não acontece isso.

Comment: Eu te pergunto pra que complicar o que está certo? Se você viu alguém fazendo pode ser que o mesmo esteja fazendo errado e você não precisa seguir a mesma linha.

Comment: Não, não, eu nunca retornaria uma um List<DalCliente> pois no meu caso DalCliente é uma classe que possui todos os métodos de consulta ao banco, ou seja, métodos do tipo `public ClientePoco ObterPorId (id)`; `public List<ClientePoco> ObterPorNome(nome)`;.

Comment: Pelos comentários percebi que não tinha me expressado bem da primeira vez, por isso fiz alguns edits fornecendo exemplos de código.

Comment: O que tem dentro de `ClienteModel`? preciso dessa classe para orientar

Answer (score 3):

Quando você cria um Projeto Asp.Net MVC, a pasta Models criada automaticamente tem esse proposito, ou seja, está dentro da solução principal. Mas nada impede de você criar outro projeto e colocar o seu Model lá. Eu já trabalhei onde o Model ficava dentro da solução principal, fora da solução como Projeto. 
Eu já criei Models em uma Dll específica, eu acho melhor, centralizado em único ponto. Mas tem gente que não gosta.